# colnames intgroup arguement of arrayQualityMetrics package of Biobase

Tags: r

I am using a package from Biobase : arrayQualityMetrics for creating the plots for visualization of microarray data.

My data is stored in ExpressionSet.
one of the column names of the phenoData(ExpressionSet) has name "Tissue" but when i run the following command :

```
arrayQualityMetrics(ExpressionSet,intgroup = "Tissue")
```

It gives me an error saying that :

```
Error in prepdata(expressionset, intgroup = intgroup, do.logtransform = do.logtransform) : 
  all elements of 'intgroup' should match column names of 'pData(expressionset)'.
```

I dont understand why I ma getting this error although my ExpressionSet contains a column names "Tissue" in its phenoData.

Comment: Have you asked on the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) mailing list, where there is a higher concentration of knowledgeable people? No subscription required. Remember to cc the `packageDescription("arrayQualityMetrics")$Maintainer`, use a current version of R and the package, include the output of `sessionInfo()`, and provide some evidence (e.g., `expressionset$Tissue` that your data is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile since you asked this question but this is likely due to arrayQualityMetrics() having to trim down the data frame in your pData() slot to a limited number of fields for display in the metadata table at the beginning of the report.

Try something like:

```
tmp <- pData(ExpressionSet)
pData(ExpressionSet) <- tmp[,c("Tissue", "SomeOtherInterestingField")] # swap out
arrayQualityMetrics(ExpressionSet,intgroup="Tissue")
pData(ExpressionSet) <- tmp # replace with your original full pData() data frame
```